# Configure chef zero server with existing chef server

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant, chef-solo

I wish to use chef zero with vagrant for provisioning developer environments. These developers are involved in application development and are not involved in maintaining chef recipes.

I have a chef server which acts as a repository for all chef components. Is it possible to configure chef zero with this chef server, so that a developer can leverage the roles and environments?

I can use berkshelf to download cookbooks using `chef_api` but role's runlist and environment's attributes will have to replicated in Vagrant file.

The advantage with this approach is that a developer can replicate `production` or `QA` environments by changing environment in Vagrantfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have discovered [Berkshelf](http://berkshelf.com/) is a great tool for managing cookbooks, but there is no equivalent tool for managing entities like roles, environments and databags. This makes sense as these entities amount to pieces of global data specific to a particular instance of chef.

There are alternative ways to work-around this:

1. Use "application" cookbooks containing "role recipes" that detail
   the desired run-list
2. Export the desired roles and environments and keep a copy in the vagrant repo

### Application cookbook pattern

Instead of using a role you use a recipe from a special "application" cookbook.  Each recipe is designed to capture the run-list of a particular component of your application: db, appserver, router, etc.

For example the "myapp::db" recipe:

```
include_recipe "mysql::server"
include_recipe "database"
include_recipe "myapp::_db_schema"
```

And the "myapp::appserver" recipe

```
include_recipe "apache2"
include_recipe "php"
..
include_recipe "myapp::_appserver_setup1"
include_recipe "myapp::_appserver_setup2"
```

The major advantage of this approach over roles is the ability to revision control changes to the run-list (dev/test/prod) and the use of a tool like Berkshelf to control chef server loading.

### Export roles and environments from chef server

If you have admin credentials it's easy to export data from chef server. See:

http://docs.opscode.com/knife_download.html

Comment: Thanks for you reponse. My main goal is to replicate production, staging and QA environments on developer machine. In our organization if a bug comes on production, a developer has to replicate the environment manually in his/her machine and the process is not standardized. If I can leverage the environment, roles used for actual production from chef server, it would greatly reduce the effort. Hence I am looking for bootstraping/replicating chef zero with chef server.

Comment: I think my use case becomes quite complex when the number of cookbooks increase in the system. Downloading all the cookbooks from chef server and uploading them on a chef zero server will be time consuming. If I wish to optimize this I will have to read the runlist of roles and use berkshelf to download these cookbooks along with their dependencies. I guess using `chef_client` is the easiest option here.

Comment: @Vaibhav Berkshelf is the tool designed to make cookbook management simpler. It's a file that can be revision controlled and distributed alongside the Vagrantfile you're using to replicate the production system. Yes, there is an overhead in loading chef-zero, but this is offset by Berkshelf's ability to cache files and the benefits of true isolation from the production system. Everyone sharing the same chef server creates tight coupling between developers.

Comment: Yes I can mention all the cookbooks which will run in chef run in Berksfile but this leads to duplicacy as the same cookbooks are defined in the runlist of a role and since I wish to replicate the role in a developer environment, there will be a maintainance overhead.

Comment: @Vaibhav No, you missed my point above.... To avoid overhead of using roles, don't use them! Replace them with a cookbook recipe. The Berksfile then lists all the cookbooks to be loaded into your chef server. Functionally the same as a Gemfile in Ruby or a Pom.xml file in Java.